# How get data from web

Tags: javascript, api, web-scraping

i trying to get data from this URL ( https://covid.saude.gov.br/ ).

I looking for the data series, not the data in table and charts.

This website have a button for download .csv, this .csv was enought for me, but i dont know how get it automatically in my javascript code.

Thank you

Comment: Please read the tags you are using. [tag:api] says you shouldn't use it, and [tag:web-scraping] says that it is something used when an API is not available!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var button = document.getElementById("<%= abc.ClientID %>");
            button.click();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: i looking for the content of csv to use in my script and update infos in my website